# UISearchBar embedded in UIBarButtonItems (Only available in iPad documents)?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.5, uisearchbar

I'm trying to insert an UISearchBar to my Toolbar of my TableView but it fail to built my app (iOS5.1) with this error

```
UISearchBar embedded in UIBarButtonItems (Only available in iPad documents)
```

http://img.muse-gaming.org/file/1359259573-uisearchbar.png

And i really can't figure it out...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That being said, it might be possible to make your own view that looks and works like a `UIToolbar` that does allow a `UISearchBar`.

Solution is that Use a navigation bar instead of a toolbar. Set the search bar to the navigation bar's title view.

[image]

**Or Yu can add it Programmatically**

```
self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(70, 3, 230, 44);
    UIToolbar  * searchToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0+20,[self view].bounds.size.width,52)];
     UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Update" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(infoButtonClicked)];

    UIBarButtonItem  * searchBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.searchBar];

    [searchToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,infoButtonItem,searchBarButtonItem, nil] animated:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:searchToolbar];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple fixed this in **Xcode 8.2**. I think they disabled it before because popovers were not allowed on iOS before iOS 8.0 and a search bar in a toolbar implies that a popover will be used most times.